# Can a Water Kineticist move himself with Deflecting Wave?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, kineticist

A [Water Kineticist](https://2e.aonprd.com/Elements.aspx?ID=6) with Single Gate can move the target of impulses:

> After the impulse's other effects, you can move one creature **targeted by the impulse or in its area** 5 feet in any direction, or 10 feet if it's in a body of water. This can't move the creature into the air. You can choose only a creature that's willing to be moved, that failed its save against the impulse, or that you succeeded at an impulse attack roll against.

[Deflecting Wave](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=4266) has not explicit target, but you cannot use on anyone else, *making you the implicit target*.

**Can you move yourself with this combination?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An impulse junction only triggers when you use an impulse that takes two actions or more.

> In addition, you gain an impulse junction, a benefit that occurs when you use an impulse of the chosen element that takes 2 actions or more. This happens before the other effects of the impulse, unless noted otherwise. You can gain only one impulse junction per round; they are described in full below.

Deflecting Wave takes a reaction, which is not two actions or more, so is unaffected by the water kineticist's impulse junction.